# Setting Phantomjs page settings in grunt-mocha

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, mocha.js

When using `grunt-mocha`, is it possible to set PhantomJS [Page settings](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) in the Gruntfile?

Specifically, i'd like to modify `webSecurityEnabled` and `localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled` to enable cross-origin requests.

Setting `page.settings.(optionname)` in the task's target options didn't to the trick. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this feature is currently open as a [pull request](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha/pull/62) on their GitHub repo, I'll just have to wait for them to merge it.

Update:

The pull request was a bit off so i made my own fork and created a new PR. If anyone is having the same issues, try this [fork](https://github.com/sessio/grunt-mocha) (you can use a custom github repo for a package's 'version' in npm's package.json)